# Create table on database with form on laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel, controller

I have a problem here. 
I want to create a table in database based on the user input. I don't know if i must do it throught controller or throught migration?

Comment: As a general rule, one's schema should be static (absent changes to one's application code that require a schema change). So the very fact that you're asking this question is highly indicative of poor database design.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just want to know if is possible, I am working the database structure if my app, maybe you are right. I will do it different.

Comment: @Enrique Berrueta

Create applications in your own well-being and create the objects / tables and their attributes is the future. Imagine how good this would be! Breaking paradigms is the work of visionaries. Do not be discouraged and let me know if you can make progress on this! I am finishing my college now and I intend to study and develop this subject based on Laravel. I'm calling this organic application.